# How can I download files from shared Amazon Cloud Drive links through the command-line?

Tags: command-line, download, wget, amazon-cloud-drive

I have been using Amazon Cloud Drive (ACD) for a while now and I am very happy someone has developed a command-line-client for it (called `acd_cli`). It allows me to keep my files in "sync" with my computers even when logging in over `ssh` in a terminal (generally running on some type of unix system).

However, from time to time I would like to access shared files from ACD. (People can create shared links for this purpose through the website interface similar to shared links in Dropbox).

Unfortunately, these links only show an interactive website, where you manually have to click on the file and press a download button, which then seems to generate a temporary download link to the actual file of interest.

**What I would like to do, is being able to download a shared file with `wget` (or at least a comparable tool) through a command-line-interface.** If anyone has found a way to access the actual file-download-link without using the website, please share your findings.

The shared link will look something like this:

https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/ABCDEFG...

The actually generated download link stays valid for at least 20 min (I just tested this), but I assume it is temporary, which is fine, but I can only get it through the website right now:

https://content-na.drive.amazonaws.com/cdproxy/templink/VWXYZ...

*[Comments]*

Maybe there is a way through the [RESTful API](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/) Amazon is providing for ACD, but that generally appears to only allow you to access **your own** files, not shared links form someone else. There is also this somewhat related thread on their developers forum, which confirms that Amazon doesn't really want you to serve HTML content from ACD: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=15698&#15698

Answer (score 2):

i dont know if this would help, but this chrome extension(amazon cloud drive link extarctor) shows the real links  on a shared folder so you can download using anything you want. 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/amazon-cloud-drive-link-e/blcjinjblhmpmogafadcppekfdfnfgdm

Comment: It's an interesting extension, but I still have to open a browser and navigate to the shared folder page, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid. What I was (am) looking for is the same functionality as the extension, but in a simple (e.g. python) script.

Comment: I bought/downloaded/used that plugin. It only selected the first 60 items on a page that contained 1200+ items.

Answer (score -1):

This python script I wrote can help you.

https://bitbucket.org/hwiorn/acdsl_cli

The download page lists the installation process and more detailed useage guides but you can list files with `acdslcli list <shared link url> <path>` and download them with `acdslcli download <shared link url> <path>`

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: I've made a start on improving the answer. As the author, you might want to improve on my improvement further. While we typically delete link only answers, this sees interesting. I've also made it clear you're the author, as per the rules here.

Comment: *acdsl_cli* seems outdated. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Does not work. Neither listing nor downloading. `acdsl_cli.exe --region de ls https://www.amazon.de/photos/share/mine .`: Error while listing directory: Expecting value: line 6 column 1 (char 5)